# How can I make my question better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I considerably modified [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870960/i-get-the-error-error-cl-cl-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-try-to-build) and I felt I included sufficient amount of information to explain what I did and also the errors I got.

I am not sure why I have been voted down for it. **How can this question be further improved?**

Comment: Ignore my last comment (if you saw it). I actually don't think there is much more. For me at least it looks like a well structured question. It's harder to get upvotes than it it's to get downvotes on a question. Sometimes it just takes a little time.